# How can the TARDIS be late?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, tardis

I was reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78713/why-didn-t-the-tardis-let-clara-in-and-get-to-trenzalore-quicker) question about the *Doctor Who* episode *"The Time of the Doctor"*, and I had a case of [Fridge Logic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic) trope.

How can a time machine be **late** ?

In this case it took the **TARDIS** 300 years to travel from point A (*Earth*) to point B (*Trenzalore*).
While the journey there might of taken a lot of time, how come she didn't arrive in Trenzalore at the required time ?

Is there an *(in-universe)* explanation *( other than 'Moffat logic' )* ?

Comment: It's an error-prone vehicle even when the Doctor's piloting it.  See Season 1 and Rose's little "missing person" case.

Comment: @Radhil Yeah but "The Doctor's Wife" episode actually explained these "errors" as the TARDIS acting by itself and sending the Doctor where he'd be needed or something like that.

Comment: I honestly thought that was what you were referring to by 'Moffat logic'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret the "lateness" as meaning that **Clara's presence made it arrive 300 years later than it was supposed to**.

By the time she latched onto it, it had already started to disappear, presumably with coordinates set for Trenzalore 300 years earlier than it actually arrived. With an unplanned passenger on the outside, the calculations for getting it to the right place and time were slightly off, and so it arrived at the wrong time (300 years late).

> CLARA: I was in space.
>   DOCTOR: Well, you were in the Time Vortex. She must have extended the force field. No wonder. No wonder she's late, dragging you around.

How do you even define "speed" in the Time Vortex? Being 'late' while travelling through time makes about as much sense as visualising time travel using a picture of a physical vortex.

We see the same effect when Jack Harkness hitches a lift on the outside of the TARDIS in the series 3 episode *Utopia*. In this case, his unexpected arrival causes the TARDIS to move way *way* into the future, to the very end of the universe.

Comment: Yeah I already thought, but the TARDIS is kind of sentient ( see "The Doctor's Wife" ), so I'd expect it could of "set the date to 300 years before intended", so that + the trip means it would arrive at the intended time. Anyway I'm gonna wait to see if there is some other answer accounting for the sentient TARDIS, otherwise I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: @RickSanchez Only if it (or rather *she*) knew beforehand that she was going to have an unexpected passenger. My thesis is that the TARDIS set the controls for Trenzalore without knowing Clara was going to jump on board, and then moved more 'slowly' through the Time Vortex because she hadn't taken account of Clara in the calculations.